# Getting “NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.setJar” error when building sample Kylin cube

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, cloudera-manager, kylin

I am trying to setup Kylin 1.6 on my cloudera cluster(5.9). Setup was successful but when i am trying to build sample cube i am getting this error

```
org.apache.kylin.job.exception.ExecuteException: org.apache.kylin.job.exception.ExecuteException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.setJar(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:123)
        at org.apache.kylin.job.impl.threadpool.DefaultScheduler$JobRunner.run(DefaultScheduler.java:136)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.kylin.job.exception.ExecuteException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.setJar(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:123)
        at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.DefaultChainedExecutable.doWork(DefaultChainedExecutable.java:57)
        at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:113)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.setJar(Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.common.AbstractHadoopJob.setJobClasspath(AbstractHadoopJob.java:162)
        at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.steps.FactDistinctColumnsJob.run(FactDistinctColumnsJob.java:88)
        at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.MRUtil.runMRJob(MRUtil.java:92)
        at org.apache.kylin.engine.mr.common.MapReduceExecutable.doWork(MapReduceExecutable.java:120)
        at org.apache.kylin.job.execution.AbstractExecutable.execute(AbstractExecutable.java:113)
```

I am not able to find out the solution for it.Can anyone please help me in this case?

Comment: Not sure kylin works on CDH 5.9, please try on CDH 5.8. And also please download the right binary. http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/kylin/apache-kylin-1.6.0/apache-kylin-1.6.0-cdh5.7-bin.tar.gz

Comment: Pretty sure you have classpath problem. Should analyze the kylin.sh, print out the actual classpath, and check the effective hadoop jar on it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.It was classPath issue i corrected it and then it worked

Comment: @AbhhayNaik I had the same problem, can you  explain more clearly?

Comment: If you are using cloudera then you will find that somehow in your class path hadoop-mapreduce0.20 folder jar files are loaded while running kylin job but in this folder it contains the older code so in this code it does not have setJar method and thats why it is causing the problem when i removed this path from classpath it worked fine for me